# How to prevent XXE attack (XmlDocument in .NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, xml-parsing

We had a security audit on our code, and they mentioned that our code is vulnerable to EXternal Entity (XXE) attack. I am using following code -

```
string OurOutputXMLString=
"<ce><input><transaction><length>00000</length><tran_type>Login</tran_type></transaction><user><user_id>ce_userid</user_id><subscriber_name>ce_subscribername</subscriber_name><subscriber_id>ce_subscriberid</subscriber_id><group_id>ce_groupid</group_id><permissions></permissions></user><consumer><login_details><username>UnitTester9</username><password>pDhE5AsKBHw85Sqgg6qdKQ==</password><pin>tOlkiae9epM=</pin></login_details></consumer></input></ce>"

 XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
 xmlDoc.LoadXml(OurOutputXMLString);
```

In the audit report they say that it's failing because an XML entity can contain URLs that can resolve outside of intended control. XML entity resolver will attempt to resolve and retrieve external references. If attacker-controlled XML can be submitted to one of these functions, then the attacker could gain access to information about an internal network, local filesystem, or other sensitive data.
To avoid this I wrote the following code but it doesn't work.

```
MemoryStream stream =
    new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(OurOutputXMLString));

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();

settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 6000;
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(reader);
```

But I can see here that reader does not have any value to load into `xmlDoc(XmlDocument)`.
Can anyone help where I am missing things?

Comment: If you are certain that you are not going to use external resources you can control the credentials the XmlDocument's XMLResolver uses. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.xmlresolver.aspx for an example. In this instance, you could set the XmlResolver's credentials to an account that has only limited access rights, so any attempt to retrieve resources can be controlled via NT permissions.

Comment: In fact, here is a very useful MSDN article which addresses your question: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335713.aspx

Answer (score 57, accepted):

External resources are resolved using the `XmlResolver` provided via `XmlDocument.XmlResolver` property. If your XML documents **should not contain any external resource **(for example DTDs or schemas) simply set this property to `null`:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.XmlResolver = null;
xmlDoc.LoadXml(OurOutputXMLString);
```

If you want to filter where these URLs come from (for example to allow only certain domains) just derive your own class from `XmlUrlResolver` and override the `ResolveUri()` method. There you can check what the URL is and sanitize it (for example you can allow only URLs within your local network or from trusted sources).

For example:

```
class CustomUrlResovler : XmlUrlResolver
{
    public override Uri ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(baseUri, relativeUri);
        if (IsUnsafeHost(uri.Host))
            return null;

        return base.ResolveUri(baseUri, relativeUri);
    }

    private bool IsUnsafeHost(string host)
    {
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Where `IsUnsafeHost()` is a custom function that check if the given host is allowed or not. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1412538/how-to-tell-if-a-url-is-an-intranet-url) here on SO for few ideas. Just return `null` from `ResolveUri()` to *save* your code from this kind of attacks. In case the URI is allowed you can simply return the default `XmlUrlResolver.ResolveUri()` implementation.

To use it:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.XmlResolver = new CustomUrlResolver();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(OurOutputXMLString);
```

For more details about how XML external resources are resolved just read [Resolving External Resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/resolving-external-resources?view=netframework-4.7) on MS Docs. If your code is more complex than this example then you should definitely read [Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.xmlresolver?view=netframework-4.7#remarks) for [XmlDocument.XmlResolver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.xmlresolver) property.

Comment: Wow! Thanks Adriano for this and this worked for me. Thanks Dash for the info.

Comment: Since **.NET Framework** version **4.5.2** (including **.NET**), the default value of the `XmlResolver` property in `XmlDocument` is `null`.

Answer (score 8):

So its better to use

```
new XmlDocument { XmlResolver = null };
```

Interestingly from .net 4.5.2 and 4.6, the default resolver behaves differently and does not use an XmlUrlResolver upfront implicitly to resolve any urls or locations as i seen.

```
//In pre 4.5.2 it is a security issue.
//In 4.5.2 it will not resolve any more the url references in dtd and such, 
//Still better to avoid the below since it will trigger security warnings.
new XmlDocument();
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the XmlReaderSettings.DtdProcessing to DtdProcessing.Prohibit works totally fine in .NET 4.7.2. Here is what i used to test.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE demo 
[
  <!ELEMENT demo ANY >
  <!ENTITY % extentity SYSTEM "https://www.hl7.org/documentcenter/public/wg/structure/CDA.xsl">
  %extentity;
]>
<test>
    Some random content
</test>
```

Saved the above content in a file and read the file from the following fragment of c# code.

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
settings.MaxCharactersFromEntities = 6000;
//The following stream should be the filestream of the above content.
XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream, settings);
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(reader);
```

I get the following exception.

```
For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD 
processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and 
pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDoctypeDecl()
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
```