# Is XmlTextReader susceptible to XXE attacks?

Tags: c#, xmltextreader, xxe

We read our XML template files using System.Xml.XmlTextReader. If there is XXE in the XML file we're reading, will that XXE be processed?

If so, major security problem. Can it be turned off?

thanks - dave

Comment: This may help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32203024/how-to-configure-the-xml-parser-to-disable-external-entity-resolution-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Covered extensively [by owasp](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_(XXE)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#.NET).