# XElement.Parse && XDocument.Parse are vulnerable to XML injection in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, fortify

The below code are detected as XML injection by fortify. Please someone help me to fix the issue.

```
LockUserXml(string xml)
{
   var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
   ..
   ..
}

LocalUserXml(XmlElement root, ExportXmlParameter param)
{
   XElement rootElement = XElement.Parse(root.OuterXml);
   ..
   ..
   ..
}
```

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca3009#how-to-fix-violations):

> **How to fix XML violations**
>
> - Don't write raw XML. Instead, use methods or properties that XML-encode their input.
> - Or, XML-encode input before writing raw XML.
> - Or, validate user input by using sanitizers for primitive type
>   conversion and XML encoding

What you can do is that use `Load` instead of `Parse` with configured reader setting(See [XmlReaderSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreadersettings)) as following:

```
LockUserXml(string xml)
{
   var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), new XmlReaderSettings() { XmlResolver = null });
   var doc = XDocument.Load(xmlReader);
   ..
   ..
}
```

See also [How to prevent XXE attack ( XmlDocument in .net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14230988/how-to-prevent-xxe-attack-xmldocument-in-net)